# Grails Build Fail With Exception

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails 3.1.6 while trying a database migration I faced a build Fail.
I Used `grails dbm-generate-gorm-changelog createGame.groovy` 
and here is the console output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'dbmGenerateGormChangelog' not found in root project 'gamereview'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I manually added

`compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC4'` and

```
compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.3.2'   in 
`build.gradle`  file
```

Is there any problem with the importing? Help Needed.

**Solution:**

Added  `classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC4'` in main section in build.gradle. 
That solved the Probelm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins with commands (this includes database-migration and hibernate and a few others) need to be in the 'main' dependencies block (with other plugins and regular jar dependencies) so the classes are available to the running app, but since Gradle runs the commands they also need to be in the dependencies block in the `buildscript` block, e.g.

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      maven { url 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core' }
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
      ...
      classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC4'
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example build.gradle  please ?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example `buildscript` block.